# Reading and storing data into array using different .java file

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-interface, int

I have 2 different Java file
Mark.java

```
public class Mark
//class'name has to be the same with file's name
{
private String studentName;
private int studentMark;
//studentName and studentMark are private instance variables
//which cannot be accessed by other classes

public Mark() //a default constructor
{studentName = "unknown"; studentMark = 0;} //giving a starting value
public Mark(String n, int m) //a parameterised constructor
{studentName = n; studentMark = m;}

//2 set mthods
public void setname (String n)
{studentName = n;}
public void setmark (int m)
{studentMark = m;}

//2 get methods
public String getname()
{return studentName;}
public int getmark()
{return studentMark;}


//get Grade method
public String Grade;
//"final" means constant
final int PASS = 50;
final int CREDIT = 65;
final int DISTINCTION = 75;
final int highDISTINCTION = 85;

{
    //if statement
    if (studentMark < PASS)
        Grade = "F";
    else if (studentMark < CREDIT)
        Grade="P";
    else if (studentMark < DISTINCTION)
        Grade="C";
    else if (studentMark < highDISTINCTION)
        Grade="D";
    else
        Grade="HD";
}

public void setGrade (String g) {Grade = g;}
public String getGrade() {return Grade;}
}
```

And GUI.java

```
import javax.swing.*; //to run JFrame
import java.awt.*; //to run FlowLayout
import java.awt.event.*; //to run ActionListener
import javax.util.*;
public class MarksGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//declare class instance variables
String studentName = nameField.getText();
int studentMark = Integer.parseInt(markField.getText());
final int MAX_STUDENT = 10;
//declare maximum student constant
private Mark [] markArray = new Mark[MAX_STUDENT];
//declare current student variable
private int currentStudent = 0; //to count the numbers of students from 0 to 9
markArray[currentStudent] = new Mark (studentName, studentMark);

   private void enterStudentNameAndMark()
    {

    }
```

Currently I am trying to find a way so that the name and mark input data would be processed through the mark.java and store in the array, what would be the most efficient way to do this>

Comment: The GUI has a lot more code in it but I just post what I think is relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you could call the method as soon as the parameterized constructer is called.

As you call the constructor in the array, the Grade would be generated.

Or you could call the the constructor in your actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your "if statements" into the constructor or to another `private` method and add it into the constructor.

***NOTE:*** don't make `public` because you will use it in the constructor as a grade init method

```
private void updateGrade(int studentMark){
    if (studentMark < PASS)
       Grade = "F";
    else if (studentMark < CREDIT)
       Grade="P";
    else if (studentMark < DISTINCTION)
       Grade="C";
   else if (studentMark < highDISTINCTION)
      Grade="D";
   else
      Grade="HD";

}
```

don't forget to update Grade in setters.

```
public void setmark (int m){
    studentMark = m;
    updateGrade(m);
}
```